# SendGrid on Heroku fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I setup send grid starter for my heroku app.

I put this in my config/environment.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  :password => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  :domain => "my-sites-domain.com",
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I create this class models/notifier.rb:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base

  def notify()
    mail( 
      :to => "my-email@gmail.com",
      :subject => "New Website Contact",
      :body => "body",
      :message => "message",
      :from => "website@my-sites-domain.com"
    )
  end

end
```

I put this in another controller to send the email:

```
def contact
  Notifier.notify().deliver
  redirect_to("/", :notice => "We Have Received Your Request And Will Contact You Soon.")
end
```

When I deploy and try to send an email I get this error:

**Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password**

I have setup send grid completely and it says I am ready to send emails.

I also ran `heroku config --long` to get the actual password and user name and hard coded them and that still gave me the same error.

Comment: Have you gone through [heroku sendgrid configurations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid)

Comment: Has your account been provisioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had tried to set my password with the command:

```
heroku config:add SENDGRID_PASSWORD=my-new-password
```

But it  turns out this only changes what heroku has stored as your password, it doesn't actually change your password. You also cannot retrieve your password after doing this.

What I had to do was remove and re-add the sendgrid add on.

Comment: To clarify, `heroku config:add` or `heroku config:set` is simply setting an environment variable on your Heroku stack. In Ruby you would access it as `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']`. You can also view the value of an environment variable on Heroku: `heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 5):

RoR + SendGrid + Heroku:

I came across similar problem where I kept receiving this error
**Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password** when I was trying to send email.

I tried

- username with which I signed up with sendgrid, and
- also the one heroku generated (when I commissioned the addon).

Answer is very simple.

**DO not** use any username. It is simple text `'apikey'` and for password use the generated API key that you got from Dashboard.

More here #
https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us

> **What is my SMTP Username and Password?**
>
> We recommend using "apikey" for your SMTP username and creating an API Key to use for your password. For more information, click here.
> https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api/

Comment: For me it was `apikey` (all lower case)

Comment: @stevec you are correct, I've edited my answer. Thanks!