# How to get heroku SendGrid addon username and password when not available in env variables?

Tags: heroku

When using the heroku SendGrid addon, heroku automatically creates a SendGrid account for you. Then you can view the credentials it created for you with

```
heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD
```

Suppose I set those to different values or otherwise delete those env variables, how would I be able to see them again? (note: via CLI or browser is fine)

I know I could [create a new SendGrid account by removing and re-adding the heroku addon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058654/5783745) but I am curious to know if there's a way without doing that?

Comment: "Suppose I set those to different values or otherwise delete those env variables" Don't?

Comment: @ceejayoz Agree, prevention is the best cure. And I haven't deleted/modified them. But I know people will do this (especially when adding 2FA to their SendGrid account), and I want to know how to solve when they do.

Comment: I suspect `heroku addons:detach` / `heroku addons:attach` will do the trick, but cannot confirm from personal experience.

Comment: You may not be able to change those values. I haven't used Heroku recently, but in a recent (now-deleted) question I saw somebody report "Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL" when trying to overwrite the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. Might be worth trying to see what happens.